# How do you insert into two tables simultaneously?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("INSERT INTO Threads(");//How can i modify that statement
sb.Append(" SELECT @Repuation, @WiningComment");
sb.Append(" FROM Users AS u");
sb.Append(" INNER JOIN Threads AS t ON t.UsersID=u.UsersID");
sb.Append(" WHERE t.ThreadsID=@ThreadID");
```

I have users table and threads table. I want to insert the @Reputation into the users table and @winingComment into the threads table!! How do i achieve that?

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot insert into two tables simultaniously in a single query. What you CAN do is run a query batch in one go.. so multiple INSERTS but executed as batch - are these two tables linked by a foeriegn key - it's not clear from the query above how the relationships are defined ?

Comment: By simultaneously you mean that the two inserts together are one atomic operation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server: Is it possible to insert into two tables at the same time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175066/sql-server-is-it-possible-to-insert-into-two-tables-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to do 2 seperate `INSERT` statements as you can't insert data into 2 tables simultaneously.

Comment: So can i append another insert statement to the sb.. and give it to the SQLcommand to execute?!?

Comment: I would recommend executing the first SQL statement, and then use the `sb` for the second and then execute it.

Comment: @Matrix001: Yes. See my answer. @Neil is right - they must be two distinct statements.

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest you to do 2 separate INSERT in a TRANSACTION

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
INSERT [...]
INSERT [...]
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Technically, the transaction guaranties the atomicity of your requests.

Comment: This way you are sure that both inserts will happen, not just one of them if the other fails.

Answer (score 2):

I think you would just do two separate INSERT statements.  If you want to make sure that this is an atomic operation (either both or neither get inserted) then you can wrap them in a transaction.  When the transaction is commited, the inserts are done simultaneously.

Hope that helps,

John

Answer (score 0):

You can't. They are going to have to be two statements no matter how you look at it. You could use a trigger to emulate the feel of doing a single `INSERT`, but that's got pretty bad code smell IMO.

If you just want to send the statements on a single command, terminate the first with a semi-colon and send it as one batch to a `SqlCommand`.

```
new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Table1 (ID) SELECT 1; INSERT INTO Table2 (SomeField) SELECT 'Some value.';", some_db_connection).ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Merge statement of Sql 2008 may help in performing operations in multiple table.

Please check once

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/28/sql-server-2008-introduction-to-merge-statement-one-statement-for-insert-update-delete/

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx