# Is there a way to do another query within the insert query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, insert

Ok so this is the query I have...I just added the ACCOUNTID and the @accountID portion which is obviosly not working

```
INSERT INTO Leads (
    LEADID,
    CREATEUSER,
    CREATEDATE,
    FIRSTNAME,
    MODIFYDATE,
        ACCOUNTID
) 
SELECT 
       'Q' + cast(floor(999997 * RAND(convert(varbinary, newid()))) as varchar(20)) 
       ,'U6UJ9000S'
       ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
       ,'U6UJ9000S'    
       ,name
       ,@accountID

  FROM Temp
```

What I am trying to do is do an insert into the account table first and get that id and add the insert id to this insert into the leads table. Is that even possible

SO basically for each record in the Temp table i need to insert a record in the account table with no values just need the account_id so when i insert in the leads table i have the account id to make that insert

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Take a look at the `OUTPUT` clause http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setup:

```
USE TempDB;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Leads
(
    LeadID VARCHAR(64),
    CreateUser VARCHAR(32),
    CreateDate DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    FirstName VARCHAR(32),
    AccountID INT
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Accounts
(
    AccountID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    name VARCHAR(32) /* , ... other columns ... */
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Temp(name VARCHAR(32));

INSERT dbo.Temp SELECT 'foo'
UNION SELECT 'bar';
```

Query:

```
INSERT dbo.Accounts
(
    name
)
OUTPUT
    'Q' + cast(floor(999997 * RAND(convert(varbinary, newid()))) as varchar(20)),
    'U6UJ9000S',
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    inserted.name,
    inserted.AccountID
INTO dbo.Leads
SELECT name
FROM dbo.Temp;
```

Check:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Accounts;
SELECT * FROM dbo.Leads;
```

Cleanup:

```
USE tempdb;
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.Temp, dbo.Accounts, dbo.Leads;
```

Comment: That way works too, I didn't realize the INSERTS could be daisy chained like that.

Comment: @Wil it's not trivial, especially if you need data from the source table to end up in the second table but *not* the first... but in this case (assuming name and firstname are supposed to be the same) it works...

Comment: @Aaron can you explain this to me a bit ...sorry I am a PHP an mysql developer and I dont really have a total understanding of whats doing on here

Comment: I'm not sure how to explain it other than there is an OUTPUT clause which makes the inserted data available to carry forward to future operations within the same statement. So it's basically inserting into two tables within one statement, using the pseudo-table "inserted" - which holds the inserted data temporarily. I provided a link as a comment to your question so you can look at the official documentation.

Comment: In reality probably the vast majority of times you would actually want to do this there would be an FK constraint defined and you would hit the error `The target table 'dbo.Leads' of the OUTPUT INTO clause cannot be on either side of a (primary key, foreign key) relationship. Found reference constraint 'FK__Name'`. [My answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408204/is-there-a-way-to-do-another-query-within-the-insert-query/7415501#7415501) gives the workaround for that.

Answer (score 5):

The problem you will probably end up hitting in practice with Aaron's use of composable DML is that chances are in reality you will have an FK defined to constrain `Leads(AccountId)` to a valid value in which case you will hit the error.

> The target table 'dbo.Leads' of the OUTPUT INTO clause cannot be on
>   either side of a (primary key, foreign key) relationship. Found
>   reference constraint 'FK_foo'.

To avoid this issue you can use

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Leads
EXEC('
INSERT INTO dbo.Accounts
OUTPUT
    ''Q'' + cast(floor(999997 * RAND(convert(varbinary, newid()))) as varchar(20)),
    ''U6UJ9000S'',
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    inserted.name,
    inserted.AccountID
SELECT name
FROM dbo.Temp;
')
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not working because you are inserting 6 values but you are specifying only 5 columns:

These are 5 columns:

```
LEADID,
    CREATEUSER,
    CREATEDATE,
    FIRSTNAME,
        ACCOUNTID
```

Ant these are 6 values:

```
'Q' + cast(floor(999997 * RAND(convert(varbinary, newid()))) as varchar(20)) 
       ,'U6UJ9000S'
       ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
       ,'U6UJ9000S'    
       ,name
       ,@accountID
```

I don't know where you get the @accountID from, but I imagine you define it somewhere else above.

You can get `@accountID` as follows, after you do the insert to the Account table:

```
select @accountID=scope_identity()
```

And then execute the insert into the Leads table.

**UPDATE:** EXAMPLE:

```
declare @accountID int 
INSERT INTO Account (col1,col2,col...)
values ('foo','bar','baz')

select @accountID=SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO Leads (
    LEADID,
    CREATEUSER,
    CREATEDATE,
    FIRSTNAME,
        ACCOUNTID
) 
values 
(
      'Q' + cast(floor(999997 * RAND(convert(varbinary, newid()))) as varchar(20))  --leadid
       ,'U6UJ9000S' --createuser
       ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  --createdate
       ,t.name --firstname
       ,@accountID --accountID
)
```

Comment: no i have 6 and 6 it was a typo....the accountid is what my question is all about ...on the top of my question you will see i say its obviously not working

Comment: can you explain where this select @accountID=scope_identity() goes in my script

Comment: The select @accountID=scope_identity() should be the FIRST line after you do INSERT INTO Account (you mentioned in your question that you do an insert into the Account table, didn't you?) The SCOPE_IDENTITY() function returns the last id of the last record inserted into the Account table during the current scope. Read more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx

Comment: what i need to do is an insert into the account table right before i do the insert in the lead table....the @accountID was me trying to explain that...i dont any code to generate that yet

Comment: @Alex I will update my answer with a complete example using your code... stay tuned :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3421/discussion-between-alex-and-icarus)

Answer (score 1):

set a variable to Scope_identity() (which returns the last id that was created) and use that

Comment: how would i do that ...i am a mysql php developer and SQL server is kind out of my specialty

Comment: Well no offense, but if SQL Server is "kind of out of your specialty" then why are you doing SQL Server work? If you need to work with SQL Server then you should either commit to learning how SQL Server works or hire someone who already knows.

Answer (score 1):

With SQL Server 2005 or higher you can use the OUTPUT clause.

```
CREATE TABLE #Inserted (AccountID, AccountName)

INSERT Account (AccountName)
OUTPUT Inserted.AccountID, Inserted.AccountName
INTO #Inserted

SELECT AccountName
FROM Temp

INSERT Leads (
    LEADID,
    CREATEUSER,
    CREATEDATE,
    FIRSTNAME,
        ACCOUNTID
) 
SELECT 
       'Q' + cast(floor(999997 * RAND(convert(varbinary, newid()))) as varchar(20)) 
       ,'U6UJ9000S'
       ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
       ,t.name
       ,i.AccountID

  FROM Temp AS t
  JOIN #Inserted AS i ON t.AccountName= i.AccountName
```

Comment: can you explain the  #Inserted  portion and what this is

Comment: It's a temporary table. These are very basic SQL Server concepts (temporary tables, variables). What that script is doing is creating a temporary table to hold the inserted AccountIDs. the OUTPUT clause after the INSERT will output the accountid and name into #Inserted. From there you can link the newly inserted accountids back to the accountname (which I'm assuming is present) in Temp to insert into the Leads table.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare an variable, set it to the desired id and the use the variable in the insert.

Comment: Alex, press F1 in SQL Server Management studio. Click on the Search tab.