# Get identity column values upon INSERT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2008 to create a procedure.

I am using the following sql statement to insert into a audit table

```
 insert into  Listuser
 (
   UserID,
   ListID,
   AuditCreated
  )
   select
   UserID,
   ListID,
    GETDATE()
 from  ListUser where Surname='surname'
```

I am using `scope_identity()` to get the identity column from the listuser table and insert the identity column to another logs table

If the select statement contains more than 1 value, how to get the identity value of both columns and insert into logs table?

Thanjs

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you need to capture multiple identity values being inserted, I'd use the `OUTPUT` clause:

```
DECLARE @TableOfIdentities TABLE (IdentValue INT)

INSERT INTO dbo.Listuser(UserID, ListID, AuditCreated) 
  OUTPUT Inserted.ID INTO @TableOfIdentities(IdentValue)
  SELECT
      UserID, ListID, GETDATE()
  FROM 
      dbo.ListUser 
  WHERE
      Surname = 'surname'
```

This will insert all rows into your `ListUser` table, and it will output all identities generated by this INSERT into the `@TableOfIdentities` table variable

[Read more about the OUTPUT clause on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)

These values are inserted into the table variable, and you can select them out from that table variable after the insert, and do whatever you need to do with them:

```
SELECT * FROM @TableOfIdentities
```

**Update:** the use of the table variable here is just as an example - of course you can also output the data into a "normal" table in SQL Server - and you can also output multiple values for each inserted row, if you need that - so you can have something like:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Listuser(UserID, ListID, AuditCreated) 
  OUTPUT Inserted.ID, Inserted.UserID, Inserted.SurName, GETDATE() 
       INTO AuditTable(IdentValue, UserID, Surname, InsertDate)
  SELECT
      UserID, ListID, GETDATE()
  FROM 
      dbo.ListUser 
  WHERE
      Surname = 'surname'
```

Comment: @user386258: We can, but there are certain restrictions as what things the target table cannot have. Read the article linked by marc_s for more details.

Comment: @marc_s,can i insert id directly to permanent table(logs table) instead of table variable

Comment: @user386258: yes, of course you can - just use that table name, and the column the value should go into.

Comment: @AndriyM - [You can get around these restrictions with `EXEC`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408204/is-there-a-way-to-do-another-query-within-the-insert-query/7415501#7415501)

Comment: @MartinSmith: As a dynamic query solution, that's quite a decent workaround!