# How to do these 2 queries at once?

Tags: php, mysql, database

In my database there are 3 tables:

```
Posts:
-id
-title
-body
-date

Tags:
-id
-title

Posts_Tags:
-id
-post_id
-tag_id
```

When an user insert a post, my php code does 2 queries:

1. Insert the post in the **Posts** table
2. Insert a row for every tags associated with that post in the **Posts_Tags** table.

Is this the correct approach ?

Is there a way to simplify or to do 1 single query ?

Comment: The basic logic sounds correct. Can you show us some code as well?

Comment: basicly no, this question would be useful; [SQL Server: Is it possible to insert into two tables at the same time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175066/sql-server-is-it-possible-to-insert-into-two-tables-at-the-same-time)

Comment: the code is not still available :(

Answer (score 2):

Is correct approach provided you do it into a [transaction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html) (atomic operation); that is, if you insert a post and there's an error into tags insertion (or in tag association insertion), also post will not be inserted

### Update

After xRobot comment, I'd updated my answer with [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-transactions.html)

Comment: Transactions are indeed the most robust method for doing this. Any other method runs the risk of leaving your database in an inconsistent state where one insert worked but the other failed for some reason. A transaction means that if either insert fails you can rollback the database and give an error message

Comment: So do I have to use the transactions ?

Comment: I am using myisam tables, so how can I do ?