# how to insert the data in multiple tables using single query

Tags: insert

Inserting the data in multiple tables using single query

```
INSERT INTO client_1.student_info, client_1.admission_details,client_1.parent_info,client_1.student_grade_mapping,client_1.parent_student_mapping(
            year1, division, id, student_id, firstname, lastname, gender, admissionno, student_id, admissiondate, tc_date, tc_issue_date,
            student_photo, dob, is_delete,student_id, parent_id, father_name, father_age, father_education, 
            father_occupation, father_ph_no, father_ph_enabled, fatheremail, 
            creation, mother_name, mother_age, mother_education, mother_occupation, 
            mother_ph_no, mother_ph_enabled, motheremail, religion, address, 
            state, city, zipcode,sg_id, student_id, grade_id,ps_id, parent_id, student_id)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 
            ?, ?, ?,?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 
            ?, ?, ?, ?, 
            ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 
            ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 
            ?, ?, ?,?, ?, ?,?, ?, ?);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot insert data into multiple tables with a single query. You'll have to use a stored procedure or wrap two queries in a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

joel-coehoorn has already mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/175138/2118383)

In one *statement*: It's not possible

but In one *transaction*: It's possible

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
   DECLARE @DataID int;
   INSERT INTO DataTable (Column1 ...) VALUES (....);
   INSERT INTO LinkTable (Column1 ...) VALUES (....);
COMMIT
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer really depends on what Database. Like the other folks said (Which many people have answered on StackOverflow) you either need a Transaction or Stored Procedure; however, if you are using Oracle 9i then you are in business (http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=209).

Happy hunting.

Comment: Transaction or SP. Sorry those are the choices. :/

Comment: You'll have to break them up. Similar to what this gent is proposing. [http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/Postgres-and-multiple-updates-in-one-statement-td1922631.html]..might be a better example on stack somewhere. Sorry wish I had a better answer.