# save data into 2 tables in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables namely `sales` and `sales_item`. The values that will be saved in these tables are coming from a PHP form. Here's my table structure:

Sales table:

```
srfno
clientname
address
contactnumber
```

sales_item table:

```
itemid
srfno
description
quantity
serialno
description
```

My problem is that I can't insert the values to `sales_item`. I can't get the `srfno` from `sales` so that they are referenced. I can only save data to sales table. Please, help thanks!

My code for inserting to sales_item:

```
$retitem= "Select `srfno` from sales_item"; 
$psql= mysql_query($retitem,$con);  
$reti = mysql_num_rows($psql);
$reti = $reti + 1;
while($return = mysql_fetch_assoc($psql))
{
if(isset($return['srfno']))
{
$retid=$return['srfno'];
$retid=mysql_insert_id();
$addretex="Insert into `sales_item` (`sitemid`,`srfno`, `retqty`, `retdesc`,`retserial`, `exqty`, `exdesc`,`exserial`,)
VALUES (' ','$retid', '$qty', '$desc', '$serialno', ' ', ' ', ' ')";
        $ret=mysql_query($addretex);                    
                }


            }
```

Inserting to sales table:

```
 $sql="INSERT INTO `sales`(`srfno`, `datecreated`, `clientid`, `referenceno`, `returnreason`, `explanation`, `status`, `dateupdated`, `dateclosed`, `resolution`)
     VALUES('$srfno','$datecreated','$clientid','$refno','$returnreason', '$explanation', 'OPEN ', ' ', ' ', 'NULL')";
    $query=mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: After insert record in to `sales` table try `srfno = mysql_insert_id();`

Comment: What do you mean, you wrote a form that is supposed to do an insert into sales_item and it isn't working? If so can we see the code?

Comment: By the way, having the item's description in the sales_item table is not good design; the data is redundant. You should have an ITEMS table with (ITEMID, DESCRIPTION), your SALES_ITEM table should have just (SRFNO, ITEMID)

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server: Is it possible to insert into two tables at the same time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175066/sql-server-is-it-possible-to-insert-into-two-tables-at-the-same-time)

Comment: @BrianDeMilia yes. It is supposed to save data to sales and sales_item. But right now it just save data to sales table. the quantity, serialno and description don't save in sales_item table

Comment: We would need to see the code. Copy the portion related to the insert so that we can see if the problem is there, and if not there, the form.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get just inserted `srfno` into the first table, use

```
mysql(i)_insert_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned what extension you are using in php.

If you're using PDO, use [PDO::lastInsertId](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php).

If you're using Mysqli, use [mysqli::$insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php).

Then save inserted_id in **sales_item** table.