# laravel inserting into multiple tables

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 tables

```
#something - id, name, url
#something_users - id, id_something, email, password
```

**My models**

```
class Something extends Eloquent
{

    protected $table = 'something';

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];

    public $errors;


    public function User()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User', 'id', 'id_something');
    }
}

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;


    protected $table = 'something_users';

    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

    public function Something()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Something');
    }

}
```

**Controller**

```
$input = Input::all();

// also some validation
$this->db->fill($input);

$this->db->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));

$this->db->push();

$this->db->save();
```

**SQL**

```
insert into `something` (`name`, `email`, `password`) values...
```

I need to insert name into the first table(something) and email, password into second(something_users)

How to do that? I have on clue about that.

Comment: Why not use Eloquent? For example, `Something::create(array('password' => Input::get('password')));`, in addition to sanitizing and validating of course...

Comment: actually I'm using eloquent. `$this->db` is just 
  `public function __construct(Something $db){$this->db = $db;}` But I want to add data into 2 tables

Comment: No, you're going around Eloquent and straight to the DB. http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent

Comment: Either way, you need two separate queries to insert to two different tables. I'd suggest Eloquent but you can insert directly to the db as you have done.

Comment: Where do you get I'm not using eloquent? see the code.

Comment: You're using it in your Model, but not in your controller. `$this -> db` is not Eloquent as it goes around the ORM. But it's beside the point. Why not just insert to the db? `DB::table('something')->insert(
    array('name' => $name, 'email' => $email));`

Comment: see my constructor and tell me that's not Eloquent

Comment: I don't understand what you want buddy. Why aren't you inserting your queries? What am I missing here?

Comment: Because I have 2 tables which I want to insert, not only 1

Comment: You can not insert to two different tables with one query. Either write two separate queries or use a transaction. [See this answer here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175066/sql-server-is-it-possible-to-insert-into-two-tables-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your relationships are a little screwed up, you probably want to change those.  Note the `hasMany()` vs the `belongsTo()`.  If a `something` can only have one `user`, you may wish to change the function to `hasOne()` from `hasMany()` and the name of the function to `user()` only because it makes more sense that way.

```
class Something extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'something';

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('User', 'id_something');
    }
}

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    protected $table = 'something_users';

    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

    public function something()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Something', 'id_something');
    }
}
```

And then to save a `something` and a `user` and have them linked, it's pretty easy.

```
$something = new Something;
$something->name = Input::get('name');
$something->url = Input::get('url');
$something->save();

$user = new User;
$user->email = Input::get('email');
$user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));

$something->users()->save($user);
```

I'm not seeing your constructor so I don't know which model `$this->db` refers to, but you may want to replace the `somethings` or `users` depending on what you have.  To keep your dependency injection going, I'd suggest naming your dependencies what they actually are.

```
class SomeController extends BaseController {

    public function __construct(User $user, Something $something)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->something = $something;
    }

    public function someFunction()
    {
        $this->something->name = Input::get('name');
        $this->something->url = Input::get('url');
        $this->something->save();

        $this->user->email = Input::get('email');
        $this->user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
        $this->something->users()->save($this->user);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks great explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 6.

I want to add data to users table and customer table using one controller that is RegisterController.

```
<?php

 namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

 use App\User;
 use App\Customer;
 use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
 use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
 use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

 class RegisterController extends Controller
 {
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Controller
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
| validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
| provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
|
*/

use RegistersUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after registration.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}

/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \App\User
 */

//this part is my code
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'role' => '2',
    ]);

    $customer = Customer::create([
        'user_id' => $user['id'],
        'firstname' => $data['name'],
        'lastname' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'address' => '',
        'phone' => '',
        'gender' => '',
    ]);

    return $user;
     }
 }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKZj3.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FJf4.jpg)

This answer is not the best one, because this answer is just a shortcut code so that my code is not error. maybe another error will appear in the future.
but I hope my answer can solve your problem