# ASP.NET project with INSERT AND INNER JOIN queries

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I need to make a project in ASP.NET that, among other functions will be able to add new data to two tables at once.

- One table is named 'products' with columns 'name' and 'id' as PK
- The other one is named 'auctions' with columns 'bidValue' and
  'productId'.

If someone could tell me what am I doing wrong in this code. When I click the button it gives an error page with this text:

> Incorrect syntax near ','.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near ','.
>
> Source Error:

```
Line 86: comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@valueOfBid1",  valueOfBid);
Line 87: 
Line 88:                     ***comm.ExecuteNonQuery();***
Line 89:                 }
Line 90:             }
```

Here is my code:

```
 public void makeBid(string nameOfProduct, int valueOfBid)
    {
        string query = @"INSERT INTO products.name, auctions.bidValue VALUES @nameOfProduc,
                       @valueOfBid1
                       FROM products 
                       INNER JOIN auctions ON products.id = auctions.productId";
        using (SqlConnection conn = DbBroker.conn())
        {
            using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
            {
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nameOfProduc", nameOfProduct);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@valueOfBid1", valueOfBid);

                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
      
    }

 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Auction1 newBid = new Auction1();
        string productName = TextBox1.Text.Trim().ToString();
        string lbItem = ListBox1.SelectedValue;
        int bidValue = Int32.Parse(lbItem);
        newBid.makeBid(productName, bidValue);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't INSERT into multiple tables in a single SQL statement. You'll have to break it down into two separate queries - start with

```
INSERT INTO products (name) OUTPUT INSERTED.ID VALUES @nameOfProduc
```

and retrieve the ID with

```
int productID = (Int32)command.ExecuteScalar();
```

Then, use this ID in the other query:

```
INSERT INTO auctions (productID, bidValue) VALUES (@productID, @valueOfBid1)
```

Also, it is not clear to me why you should add a new record to the `products` table with each bid. It makes more sense to retrieve the product id from the products table, and then only insert a new record in the `auctions` table. That would look something like `INSERT INTO auctions(productId, bidValue) VALUES ...`

Comment: With every button click I need to insert new auction data into tables, so new Product's name and it's value. Beginner's mistake regarding the single SQL statement. So, I need to make two queries and two sqlCommand ?

Comment: It showed again error because the column does not allow null, so i changed that in table and now work's. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

T-SQL doesn't allow inserting into 2 tables in the same statement.

If you want to insert into two tables in an atomic manner, you can do it in a transaction.

That question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175066/sql-server-is-it-possible-to-insert-into-two-tables-at-the-same-time).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're attempting to do a `insert into select...` - you do indeed have a few issues.

`insert into` with a from table involved requires a `select` rather than `values`.  You can't actually insert values into two tables at once (you could use a trigger, but not exactly the same thing)

Something like this should work:

```
INSERT INTO auctions (productId, bidValue)
select p.Id,
       @valueOfBid1
FROM products p
where name = @nameOfProduc
```

note this will work dependent on "name of product" being unique.  Additionally, you should only be inserting a "product" when a new product is added to the inventory (or whatever) - each bid should not create a new product.

The above statement will successfully insert a bid for a product name in the `auctions` table, but it is dependent on the `product` already existing.