# Multiple query with ID from first one

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm working on a project but I'm stuck. I'm making a system to change the answer and question of aq quesion from the FAQ-page on a website. For that I use 2 tables in SQL. One who contains the answers and one that contains the question which contains a column for the number of which ID is connected for the answer. Bit I can't run those 2 SQL's in once, can someone help me fix the problem. I need to update my answers-table first to get the ID from the new answer to connect it to the questions-table.

Thanks in advance.

***Table Answers***
[image]

***Table Questions***
[image]

***Code for the updates***

```
<?php
include('../inc/connection.php');

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

if (isset($_POST['fields'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['fields'] as $item) {
        $values[] = $db->real_escape_string($item);
    }

    var_dump($values);

    if ($stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO AntwoordenFAQ (nl_antwoord,fr_antwoord,en_antwoord) VALUES (?,?,?);")) {

        $stmt->bind_param('sss', $values[0], $values[1], $values[2]);
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            if ($stmt->affected_rows == 1) {
                $IDinsert = $db->insert_id;
                if ($stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO VragenFAQ (nl_vraag, fr_vraag, en_vraag) VALUES (?,?,?);")) {
                    $stmt->bind_param('sss', $values[3], $values[4], $values[5]);
                    if ($stmt->execute()) {
                        if ($stmt->affected_rows == 1) {
                            echo TRUE;
                        }
                        else {
                            echo $IDinsert;
                        }
                    }
                    $stmt->close();
                }
            }
            else {
                echo FALSE;
            }
        }
        $stmt->close();
    }
    $db->close();
}
}
exit();
?>
```

Comment: Check for mysqli_errors. You're assuming everything works.

Comment: what is the problem ? what `But I can't run those 2 SQL's in once` mean?   Show us sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: `help me fix the problem` read more here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175066/sql-server-is-it-possible-to-insert-into-two-tables-at-the-same-time#175138

Comment: And read this for `LAST_INSERT_ID()` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837990/last-insert-id-mysql#3838011

Comment: You can do two statements logically at once, it is called a transaction.  This is how banks move money from one account to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saying you can't do two statements at once seems obvious but is not actually true.  SQL does give a way to do two statements logically at once.  Them means any other queries against the data base will see nothing or the results of both queries.  You do this with a transaction.  It works like this :

```sql
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

-- On systems you might need to lock tables here on others it 
-- happens automatically

-- QUERY 1
INSERT -- ...
;

-- QUERY 2
INSERT -- ...
; 

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

This is how (as an example) a bank might move cash from one account to another -- there is never a moment where two accounts have the cash or no accounts have the cash.  In the bank example the two (or more) queries would be `UPDATE` queries.