# when we create a new record in sugar the fields will be inserted into two or more table how this can be achieved from MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sugarcrm, suitecrm

when we create a new record in sugarcrm the fields will be inserted into two or more table how this can be achieved from MySQL query

i have two tables a_vendor(id,name) and a_vendor_cstm(id_c,email_c)
 i need to insert into two table at the same in order to have same id as

```
insert into a_vendor (id,name) values (auto_generated,'myname');
insert into a_vendor (id_c,email_c) values (auto_generated_same_as_id,'my email');
```

Comment: That seems risky if you are relying solely on inserting at the same time. Better yet to perform the first insert, retrieve the `id` generated and perform the second insert. You can use `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` to get the last autogenerated ID from your session after running the first `INSERT`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175066/sql-server-is-it-possible-to-insert-into-two-tables-at-the-same-time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well i found it thanks for your help
the query is as :

```
START TRANSACTION;

SET @id= uuid();

INSERT INTO a_vendor(id,name) VALUES (@id,'mynqme');

INSERT INTO a_vendor_cstm(two_id, name) VALUES (@id, 'email');

COMMIT;
```

Comment: But this is not a prefer way to do it.

Comment: amitesh Kumar  then ? glad if you share the query... :)

Comment: http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.7/Data_Framework/Database/SugarQuery/

Comment: Thanks for that reference :)