# Insert same items into three tables using a single insert query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables with same fields and same field's name. Now I want to insert same data into three tables using only one insert query.

My tables are:
temp1:

```
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id      | varchar(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name    | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| address | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

temp2:

```
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id      | varchar(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name    | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| address | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

temp3:

```
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id      | varchar(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name    | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| address | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I want to insert same value for each table.

I have tried this code:

```
insert into temp1,temp2,temp3 values('abcd','sangho','rajpur');
```

Please help me. its really important.

Comment: Why would you have 3 tables with the same schema AND the same data in them?? I cant think of a relational database rule that does not break

Comment: You generally _can't_ insert into three different tables without using three separate insert statements.  But...why are you maintaining three separate tables with identical structure in the first place?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Insert into multiple tables? (Database normalization?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178697/mysql-insert-into-multiple-tables-database-normalization)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since SQL doesn't support such statements, you could just chain the two statements using a semicolon like so

```
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES(1, 2, 3);INSERT INTO temp2 VALUES(1, 2, 3);
```

Also take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/175138/5757893) using transactions.