# SQL Insert into multiple tables and Rows

Tags: sql

For Example, Ihave 1 table table_source :

| ID | Price | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Data 1 | Price 1 | 1Nov2022 |
| Data 2 | Price 2 | 9Nov2022 |

I want to insert into 2 table ,

Table_Header:

| Number_trans | Id | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Data 1 | 1Nov2022 |
| 2 | Data 2 | 9Nov2022 |

And Table_Detail

| Number_trans | COA | Debit | Credit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaaa | xx | 0 |
| 1 | bbbb | 0 | xx |
| 1 | cccc | yy | 0 |
| 1 | dddd | 0 | yy |
| 2 | aaaa | zz | 0 |
| 2 | bbbb | 0 | zz |
| 2 | cccc | qq | 0 |
| 2 | dddd | 0 | qq |

don't worry about xx, yy, zz and qq --it's count with some formulas from price and other thing's..
For example :
xx is price 1,
yy is price 1 x 11%,
zz is price 2,
qq is price 2 x 11%.

How can I do insert into 1 row (in table_header) and 4 rows (in table_detail) from 1 single row in table_source? Can I do it with single sql statement?

insert sql into multi tables with one statement

Comment: How are getting data for columns COA, Debit & Credit in the details table?  Is it from any other table? Please provide details of that table. Also please mention the database name.

Comment: COA is fix , first row ='aaaa', 2nd = 'bbbb', 3rd = 'cccc',4th='dddd
Debit and credit are from some formulas 
For example : xx = price 1, yy = price 1 * 11%, zz = price 2, qq = price2 * 11%

Answer (score 0):

You can't insert multiple tables in one statement but you can use one transaction in a single call

Here is the reference you may find useful

[SQL Server: Is it possible to insert into two tables at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175066/sql-server-is-it-possible-to-insert-into-two-tables-at-the-same-time)